# How to solve error AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'default' using guild = interaction.guild

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to code a Discord bot with ticket functionality, and it keeps giving me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Scarlett Rivera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "c:\Users\Scarlett Rivera\Desktop\Sc4rl3ttb0t\Sc4rl3ttb0t\Sc4rl3ttb0t.py", line 98, in ticketcallback
    guild.default.role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'default'
```

every time I run the ticket command and click the button it generates.

Code:

```
async def ticketcallback(interaction):
    guild = interaction.guild
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Admin")
    role2 = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Co-Owner")
    role3 = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Owner")
    overwrites = {
        guild.default.role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False),
        interaction.user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True),
        role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True),
        role2: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True),
        role3: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True)
    }

    select = Select(options=[
        discord.SelectOption(label="Help Ticket", value="01", emoji="✔", description="This will open a help ticket"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="Other Ticket", value="02", emoji="❌", description="This will open a ticket in the other section")
    ])

    async def my_callback(interaction):
        if select.values[0] == '01':
            category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Help Tickets")
            channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f"{interaction.user.name}-ticket", category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"Created ticket - <#{channel.id}>")
            await channel.send("Hello, how can I help?")
        elif select.values[0] == '02':
            category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Other Tickets")
            channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f"{interaction.user.name}-ticket", category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"Created ticket - <#{channel.id}>")
            await channel.send("Hello, how can I help?")

    select.callback = my_callback
    view = View(timeout=None)
    view.add_item(select)
    await interaction.response.send_message("Choose an option below", view=view, ephemeral=True)

@bot.command()
async def ticket(ctx):
    button = Button(label=" Create Ticket", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    button.callback = ticketcallback
    view = View(timeout=None)
    view.add_item(button)
    await ctx.send("ticket", view=view)
```

I've narrowed it down through commenting out bits and pieces to the ticketcallback, and I thought that I could fix it by commenting it out, but then other parts of the code are not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo according to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild%20default#discord.Guild.default_role):

[image]

Your code tries to access `guild.default.role` (as shown in the error). You likely meant to access `guild.default_role`. Since `guild` objects don't have the property `default`, the interpreter doesn't know what you're trying to access.

The discord.py documentation is one of the best I have ever used - in the future if you're ever lost on what properties or methods a discord.py class implements, I highly encourage you to take a look at its [class overview](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild%20default#guild).